# The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type using API in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I want to use an API in my application. So I'm using it like below

```
IEIncrementalData objIncrement = new IEIncrementalData();
IEIncrementalData[] arrIncrementData = new IEIncrementalData[1];

objIncrement.SAPID = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text).Replace("&nbsp;","");
objIncrement.SiteRFEIDate = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[8].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");
objIncrement.SiteRFSDate = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[9].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");
objIncrement.ID_OD = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");
objIncrement.ID_OD_CHANGEDATE = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "")))
{
    objIncrement.NoofRRHBase = "0";
}
else 
{
    objIncrement.NoofRRHBase = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");
}
                    
objIncrement.SiteStatus = "".Replace("&nbsp;", "");
objIncrement.SiteDropDate = "".Replace("&nbsp;", "");
objIncrement.RRH_CHAGEDDATE = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[5].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");
objIncrement.TENANCY_COUNT = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[6].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");
objIncrement.TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE = Convert.ToString(grdDisplayFCAData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[7].Text).Replace("&nbsp;", "");

arrIncrementData[0] = objIncrement;

string apiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUrl"].ToString();
var inputIPColoMaster = new
{
    IEIncrementalData = arrIncrementData,
};
string inputJsonIPColoMaster = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(inputIPColoMaster);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string json = client.UploadString(apiUrl, inputJsonIPColoMaster);
DataTable dtRes = new DataTable();
string GISSendDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
StringReader sr = new StringReader(json);
dtRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

But while using the mentioned api, I am getting error as

> The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

the above error generated when I debug this line of code,

`string json = client.UploadString(apiUrl, inputJsonIPColoMaster);`

The generated json is below:-

```
{"IEIncrementalData":[{"SAPID":"I-PB-AMRR-ENB-I042","SiteRFEIDate":"23/10/2018","SiteRFSDate":"Approved","ID_OD":"","ID_OD_CHANGEDATE":"","NoofRRHBase":"24/10/2018","SiteStatus":"","SiteDropDate":"","RRH_COUNT":null,"RRH_CHAGEDDATE":"","TENANCY_COUNT":"","TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE":"23/10/2018"}]}
```

What exactly is the error's root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of debugging and response data which I got from the client.

Gave this a try. What I did is

`I created the Parameters with same name as the response was generating from the API`

For ex:- Earlier the response class name was `IEIncrementalData` which I was sending. But the API response was `SiteData` and it has 11 parameters. So I created the class with same name and same no of parameters.

After doing that It worked for me.!!